# Visual Studio shows npm packages as not installed

Tags: visual-studio, npm-install, visual-studio-2019

I recently moved to Visual Studio 2019 (from 2017) and editing the package.json file works fine but then I get - incorrectly - a warning on the dependencies folder in the solution view. It says that the package I modified / added is not installed, even though when I look at my node_modules folder, it is there and it's the correct version.

I tried to install it manually and when I run `npm install --no-save` (which is what VS does), the same thing happens. However when I run just `npm install`, VS removes the dependencies warning.

Is there any way to fix that? Either make VS see that the package is installed keeping the `--no-save` option, or making VS not use that option.

Comment: try this npm install --no-save -g please feedback.

Comment: `added 1 package from 1 contributor in 1.668s` but that didn't help